# azorult_sploit.py: error: the following arguments are required: target

Tags: python, parsing

this is my code

```
def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        prog="azorult_sploit.py",
        add_help=False,
        formatter_class=lambda prog: argparse.HelpFormatter(prog, max_help_position=50),
        epilog= '''
        This script will exploit the SQL vulnerability in Azorult 3.3.1 Dashboard.
        ''')
    parser.add_argument("target", help="URL of index.php (ex: http://target.com/index.php)")
    parser.add_argument("-n", "--id_record", default="1", help="id of record to dump")
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--proxy", default="http://localhost:8080", help="Configure a proxy in the format http://127.0.0.1:8080/ (default = tor)")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args
```

this is the bug:

```
usage: azorult_sploit.py [-n ID_RECORD] [-p PROXY] target
azorult_sploit.py: error: the following arguments are required: target
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)